# ol is hiding without entering the if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `ol` with `li`s into it. On the click of the `ol` I want the `ol` to be hidden, but if clicked on the `li` it should not hide. And this should happen when the screen size is below `768px`. Below is my code

```
jQuery('ol.main-nav').click(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).width() <= 768) {
        jQuery('ol.main-nav > li ').click(function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        })
        jQuery('ol.main-nav').hide(100);
    }
})
```

Actually, my code is hiding the `ol.nav-main`. While using the debugger, it doesn't go into the if condition, but still somehow executes the piece of code.

Comment: Can you create a working sample where we can debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Do a single click event, test if the clicked element is a list item or if the clicked element is a child of a list item:

```
jQuery('ol.main-nav').click(function (e) {
    if (jQuery(window).width() <= 768 && jQuery(e.target).closest('ol.main-nav > li').length) {
          e.preventDefault();
    } else {
          jQuery('ol.main-nav').hide(100);
    }
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/Lm73y2bL/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder test if the element has a parent of `ol.main-nav > li`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder nice didn't know that

Comment: Also, you don't want `&&` in your condition. It should be "If the width <= 768 OR the click was on an `li`".

Comment: Not trying to hassle you, but you also want `> 768`, not `<= 768`; you need to invert the condition as you've moved the `hide` to an `else`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder doesn't he want to prevent the click event in the mobile? why > 768?

Comment: Ignoring the `li` bit for now, the original code reads "If the width is <= 768, hide the `ol`" Your code does the opposite, because you've moved the `hide` into an `else`. (I'm also pretty sure the OP doesn't want to prevent the default, that's just what they were trying to do in the `li` case, but that's a separate thing.)

Comment: i think he wants both the hiding and the click event on <= 768,its a bit misleading

Comment: Right, but the above doesn't hide when <= 768; it hides when > 768.

Comment: it hides <=768 if the element is not a list item or a child of a list item

Comment: I see what you're saying (this goes also to my `&&` comment). I don't think that's what the OP wants, but I could be wrong. Too bad it's an ask-and-run. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
    jQuery('ol.main-nav').click(function () {  
      if (jQuery(window).width() <= 768) {           
         jQuery('ol.main-nav').hide(100);
      }
   });

   jQuery('ol.main-nav > li ').click(function (event) {  
      if (jQuery(window).width() <= 768) {     
         event.stopPropagation();
      }
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost never want to hook up an event handler inside another event handler.

You have two choices for what you're describing:

1. Check when the event occurs to see if it travelled through an `li`:

   ```
   jQuery('ol.main-nav').click(function(event) {
       var t;
       if (jQuery(window).width() <= 768) {
           for (t = event.target; t != this; t = t.parentNode) {
               if (t.tagName == "LI") {
                   return; // The click came through an LI
               }
           }
           jQuery('ol.main-nav').hide(100);
       }
   });
   ```

   or
2. Add a handler to the `li`s that stops propagation. It's much simpler:

   ```
   jQuery('ol.main-nav').click(function () {
       if (jQuery(window).width() <= 768) {
           jQuery('ol.main-nav').hide(100);
       }
   });
   jQuery('ol.main-nav > li').click(function(event) {
       event.stopPropagation(); // If you like check `width` here too
   });
   ```